# Getting around changing a constant value in C

Tags: c

I have a problem here where I get an error saying writing into a constant object. 
Well yes I know that I am, but for this function it asks the user to enter a value for dice 1-5, and the input(i) is going to be assigned to dice[i], which doesn't work, because it is constant, how do I go around this?

Thanks

```
void readDieValues(const int dice[], int nrOfDice)
{
//Reads user inut
     int i = 0;

//When i > 0 and < 5 the user is asked to entar a value for dice i+1
//Dice i+1 because i starts at 0 and dies are numbered from 1-5

    for ( ; i < 5 ; i++){
        printf("Die %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &dice[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why declare it `const` in the first place?

Comment: Remove this `const`. You don't really need it.

Comment: humm the whole idea of marking the argument const is that to tell that argument will not change when i call the function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh?

You know you're going to write into the argument but you've still declared it as `const`? Why? That doesn't make sense.

You can always try to cast away the `const`, but that's very ugly and should almost never be done, certainly not in a case such as yours:

```
scanf("%d", (int *) &dice[i]);
```

Also, you must check the return value of `scanf()`, it's brittle I/O and can fail.

Answer (score 3):

Don't declare things to be `const` if you know you are not going to treat them as constants.

You wrote the line

```
void readDieValues(const int dice[], int nrOfDice)
```

which is your contract to the world telling it that you promise not to change values.  Now that you've made that contract, you want to change values of `dice`.  Instead write

```
void readDieValues(int dice[], int nrOfDice)
```

and make no such promises